# Unable to add multiple scaling schedules in GCP VM using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

Below is the terraform code:

```
resource "google_compute_autoscaler" "default" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = "my-autoscaler"
  zone     = "us-central1-f"
  target   = google_compute_instance_group_manager.default.id
  autoscaling_policy {
    max_replicas    = 5
    min_replicas    = 1
    cooldown_period = 60

    scaling_schedules {
      name                  = "every-weekday-morning-1"
      description           = "Increase to 2 every weekday at 7AM for 1 hour."
      min_required_replicas = 2
      schedule              = "0 7 * * MON-FRI"
      time_zone             = "America/New_York"
      duration_sec          = 3600,
      name                  = "every-weekday-morning-2"
      description           = "Increase to 2 every weekday at 8AM for 1 hour."
      min_required_replicas = 3
      schedule              = "0 8 * * MON-FRI"
      time_zone             = "America/New_York"
      duration_sec          = 3600
    }
  }
}
```

When I look into https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vm/blob/master/modules/mig/variables.tf, below is variable format:

```
variable "scaling_schedules" {
  description = "Autoscaling, scaling schedule block"
  type = list(object({
    disabled              = bool
    duration_sec          = number
    min_required_replicas = number
    name                  = string
    schedule              = string
    time_zone             = string
  }))
  default = []
}
```

When I run terraform init, I get below error->

```
The argument "name" was already set ../../modules_mig/main.tf:192.7-11. Each argument may be set only once
```

when we try adding multiple schedules using gcloud utility, we are able to add but it gives error when we add using terraform

Comment: `scaling_schedules` is a list. Your example is incorrectly putting two items in one item.

Comment: I even tried in below format.scaling_schedules [{scaling schedule 1st configuration},{scaling 2nd configuration}]  this format gives me error